# Text-To-Speech in background audio task

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Background Audio Task in a WP8.1 project which uses the `BackgroundMediaPlayer` to play audio.

In my foreground app I have articles (online articles) which can be listened to. This is done via TTS (`SpeechSynthesizer`).

I have tried two things to implement this feature:

1. Creating a `SpeechSynthesisStream` in the task and use it with `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetStreamSource(IRandomAccessStream stream)`.

   Always hitting memory exceptions with this method when the text is longer than a few hundred chars.
2. Creating the stream in the foreground app and save it to a **.wav** file.
   This works with longer texts as in the first method but creates really large files and takes inacceptable long to generate and increases memory by a few hundred MB.

---

Code for the 2nd implementation:

```
string content = ".......";

// create stream from synthesizer
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(content);

// get inputstream and size of stream
ulong size = stream.Size;
IInputStream inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);

stream.Dispose();

DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream);
await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)size];
dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);
inputStream.Dispose();
dataReader.Dispose();

// open folder and file
IStorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Audio", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
IStorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("audio.wav", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

// write file
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buffer);
```

---

Any ideas how to implement this feature in a "memory-friendly" and fast way (without using online services)?